# Instrumental variable identifiability in the presence of unobserved confounders

Tags: least-squares, instrumental-variables

Long story short, I'm seeing in the literature that linear instrumental variables models are identifiable, even in the presence of unobserved confounders.  The unobserved confounding aspect befuddles me, since it is not clear where this insight came from.

Briefly, given a *linear* instrumental variables setup where

$X = Z\beta + U\theta + \epsilon, \; \epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma_{\epsilon})$

$Y = X\alpha + U\phi + \delta, \; \delta \sim N(0, \sigma_{\delta})$

where $Z\in \mathbb{R}^z$ are instruments $X \in \mathbb{R}^x$ are the exogenous variables, $Y \in \mathbb{R}^y$ are the endogenous variables and $U \in \mathbb{R}^u$ are the unobserved confounders. In the instrumental variables setup, the average causal effect $\mathbb{E}[Y|do(x)]$ is of interest.

If $U$ is observed, I can see how this works out.  But it isn't clear to me how an unobserved $U$ gets dropped / marginalized out in the linear setting, and I have not been successful finding the original proof, whether it be in Bowden + Turkington 1984, Pearl 2008 or Rubin + Imbens 2015. Any references or pointers would be appreciated.

P.S. I just realized that there are very few causality-related questions on this stack-exchange - if there are recommendations on a more appropriate forum, those are also welcome.

P.S.S Thanks to @kjetilbhalvorsen , I was able to find a [similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/550944/79569) on stats.stackexchange -- $X$ can be treated as a collider.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen thanks!

Comment: CV has some very active and very knowledgeable users in this area!